# Focus on Textarea with Zend Form

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, focus, zend-form

I've build a form with Zend Form, and would like the focus to be on a text area inside the form on page load. I tried with JS, sometimes it shows the focus for half a second, but it removes the focus before one can actually type anything.

I thought Zend Form may prevents the focus, so i looked it up, and found the autofocus attrib-option, but that won't help either.

Any idea what the matter may be?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

autofocus seems to work fine, however it is not supported in IE. So you're likely stuck with javascript for now.

I tested autofocus in firefox and IE using:

```
$element->setAttrib('autofocus', 'autofucus');
```

it work well in firefox with 2 doctypes. HTML5 and XHTML1.0

I haven't tried it in this context but putting the HTML5 shim in your header seems to make IE behave much better.

```
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Comment: $element->setAttrib('autofocus', 'autofocus'); - please change the spelling on autofocus

Answer (score 1):

If you have used dojo `getFocusOnLoad()` might help to set the focus when the a page loads..

Please follow these links:

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dojo.form.html
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html